# Странные падения при переходе c Qt 4.4.0 на Qt 4.8.1

Tags: qt, c++

Проблема в следующем.

Есть программа, написанная с Qt 4.4.0. Работала долго, без проблем.

Пересобрал ее с Qt 4.8.1. ОС Ubuntu 12.04.
Cобралось нормально.
Но теперь случаются странные падения.

Пример:

```
void XEventButton::buttonPressed() 
{ 
    XEventButtonProperty* property = static_cast<XEventButtonProperty*> propertyItem->getProperty());

    dlg->setupForExec( propertyItem->getValue(), property->getMode() ); 
    dlg->exec(); 
    propertyItem->setValue( dlg->getValue() ); 
}
```

Падение происходит в функции  `dlg->getValue()`. Указатель `dlg` вдруг стал равен `0`.

Если ставлю брекпоинт в этом месте, то `dlg` уже ненулевой, тогда падает в этой же строке, но потому что `propertyItem = 0x20` (propertyItem - указатель).

Изменил код на это:

```
void XEventButton::buttonPressed() 
{ 
    XEventButtonProperty* property = static_cast<XEventButtonProperty*>(propertyItem->getProperty());

    XEventButtonPropertyItem* tmp_prop_item = propertyItem;
    XEventDialog* tmp_dlg2 = dlg;
    dlg->setupForExec( propertyItem->getValue(), property->getMode() );     
    dlg->exec();
    propertyItem = tmp_prop_item;
    dlg = tmp_dlg2;
    propertyItem->setValue( dlg->getValue() );
}
```

и все. Падения прекратились. Что за дела? Я не понимаю, что происходит.

Есть еще несколько непонятных вещей, но что-то мне подсказывает, корень проблем один.

Comment: А где объявлен dlg? И откуда ещё идёт с ним работа?

Comment: @ASten, dlg - член класса XEventButton, диалоговое окно. 

dlg->exec() - появляется диалог и ждет нажатия кнопочек.
Закрываю диалог, завершается функция dlg->exec() и dlg становиться равным 0, до этого он был не равен 0.

Я предпологаю, что проблемы не в коде. Похожее повежение можно наблюдать, если например подключить к программе собраной в релизе дебажную библиотеку например.

Comment: Вернулся к этой задаче. Поробовал тоже самое под Windows. Падает в том же месте.